# Select a certain item by clicking a link beside that item

Tags: selenium2, python

I have a popup with list of names. I need to choose "mahmoud" for instance by clicking the "select" link beside the label "mahmoud". How to click that select? I am using selenium webdriver with python.

```
# these 2 code lines are not working
driver.find_element_by_name('123')
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Select').click()

name
 - mahmoud   select
 - ahmed     select 
 - engy      select

# mahmoud is text,select is link
```

The HTML code for the first row is:

```
<tr class="gridRow">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Mahmoud</td>
    <td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Select</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you rewrite the question in English, please?

Comment: Tried to edit, but gave up half way.  Absolutely can't understand the question.  Please break down your question into smaller statements.

Comment: Finally edited, hopefully it doesn't change the original question

Comment: @engy, welcome to SQA.  Assuming Suchit edited your question correctly, we cannot answer your question unless we know how your HTML is structured: specifically, what the elements look like in the vicinity of each name and select link/button.

Comment: Need some more of the html.  Please provide the parent tag as that would be very useful in this case e.g. <table> tag and possibly the one above that too.

Answer (score 3):

Use XPATH.  Install a tool like FirePath to help yourself debug this, but you'll probably want something like:

```
select_finder = "//tr[contains(text(), 'Mahmoud')]//a"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(select_finder).click()
```

where the XPATH reads something like "find a table row which contains the text "Mahmoud", then find a hyperlink inside that row"

Comment: I think he/she is looking to click the "select" next to mahmoud, and seems like "mahmoud" is not a link

Comment: yeah, i think the xpath would work as long as the li contained both the text "mahmoud" and a link...

Comment: That's my point.  If the label and the select are separate elements, which it seems from the question it won't work.

Comment: I think we agree with each other - we can't tell unless we know the precise structure of the HTML the OP is using. Still, if it's a UL/LI structure, I figure it's pretty likely the LI will contain both the text and the hyperlink, so my structure would work.  but it's only an example...

Comment: hi all sorry for my poor english here is the HTML code for my question:
        <tr class="gridRow"><td>1</td>
        <td>Mahmoud</td>
        <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Edit</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Select</a>
        </td>
        </tr>

Comment: Hi engy, maybe my updated version will work? If you install Firepath, you can debug it live against your site...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you should look for the parent element of that row.  If it is in a table, then you can get the row number in which your element resides and use that.  I won't (and can't without the actual html) provide an answer, but these are the things you can do (if you haven't already):

- Read about using XPaths here - http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/.  Section 2.5 Abbreviated Syntax has been of great value to me personally
- Read about using XPaths with Selenium
- Find the XPath of the label e.g. Mahmoud.  Now that you know the row and column for the label, you can find the relative position of the corresponding "Select"

Comment: i'm using firebug with firefox to get the element's XPATH but because the table has like 5 rows each row has select link in it my question was how to choose a specific link in specific row "find_element_by_text_link" not working.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set a unique identifier for each of the links. That way, if you're looking for the select for mahmoud, you could set an id, such as `<a id="mahmoud">`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all who tried to help me with my question.

Actually I solved it using the `driver.find_element_by_xpath` method and because it's a popup it needed the `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` method until the page rendered the popup and voila, it worked.

I found the clues at Stack Overflow website.

Answer (score 0):

This relative xpath locator should also work for the above html

//td[text()="Mahmoud")]/../td[3]/a